# JQuery - Change certain element classes to specific classes if certain other element is present

Tags: jquery, layout, parent-child, parent

Hi there I'm trying to code a blog theme which will have tags etc so wat I'd like is for certain classes of mostly parent divs to change when tagged with something (example below).

classes are spans (using bootstrap)

html

```
<div id="a" class="span6">
</div>

<div id="b" class="span6">

<a class="taglink">[tag]</a>

</div>
```

What I'd like is for div a and b's classes to change to say span12, and *only* them and no other parent/adjacent/child etc divs.

This is so that when I tag the post with certain tags I'd like some of its layout properties to change (via its css class)

Answer (score 0):

Create an event listener for when the content of the a.taglink changes, then use the following:

```
$('#a.span6,#b.span6').removeClass('span6').addClass('span12');
```

Comment: This may change another elements in the page

Comment: @HighParkCoder yeah since you are using the class selector this would select anything on the page that has the class="span6" not just div id="a" and id="b"...

Comment: Got it, I wasn't clear on the paramaters.  You're absolutely right.  Wouldn't $('#a.span6,#b.span6').removeclass('class6').addClass('class12'); then work?

Comment: absolutely, and would protect against someone naming another thing with the same id, as long as they also didn't give it the same class name.

Answer (score 0):

Make a listener for the tags so that it will call the following

```
$('#a,#b').addClass('span12').removeClass('span6');
```

I hope this will help

If you want anything else for the listener please show more code

Answer (score 0):

This will select the *exact* elements you want and swap the classes:

```
$(".taglink").click(function(){
  $(this).parent("#b").removeClass('span6').addClass('span12').prev("#a").removeClass('span6').addClass('span12');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rniestroj/aKK3c/

Comment: I didn't see anything about having to click. Did I miss something?