# Jquery listener event for innerhtml

Tags: jquery, events, layout, listener, parent-child

I'm pretty new to jquery so am not too knowledgeable on it, I asked a question on using jquery to change the class of certain elements to specific classes if another certain element is present - [JQuery - Change certain element classes to specific classes if certain other element is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654387/jquery-change-certain-element-classes-to-specific-classes-if-certain-other-ele)

It seems that an event listener is needed for this, I have a basic understanding of event handlers but this is generally to do with actions such as click etc what I need however is one to Id if certain elements innerhtml has a text value (e.g. 'go') to run a function on near by elements (example below).

This is for a blog, which will use certain tags to change layout of posts, below there is some repeated html to illustrate how the targetting needs to work

classes are spans (using bootstrap)

html

```
<div class="container">

<div  class="span6">
</div>

<div class="span6">
<a class="taglink">text</a>
</div>

</div>

<div class="container">

<div class="span6">
</div>

<div class="span6">
<a class="taglink">text</a>
</div>

</div>
```

What I'd like is for a & b's and *only* a & b's classes to change from span 6 to 12 when the text inside one of the a classes 'taglink' that is *within* the same container div is equal to 'go'.

This is so that only 'go' tag will affect only 'a' and 'b' divs classes and only that of a and b within its own 'container' div.

Comment: Do you want to have to click the link. Or does it just happen when the page loads.

Comment: You can't have two elements with the same id.

Comment: fixed the write up, no more id's

Comment: after your latest edit (wherein you removed the ids), none of the elements have id or class or name or anything == a OR b, and your question no longer makes sense as a result

Answer (score 0):

Now the first order of business:

Ids MUST MUST be unique, this is non-negotiable.

So, I am going to make the following assumptions:

1. every instance of `id=a` or `id=b` or `id=container` (the multiples) actually read `class=a`, `class=b`, and `class=container` respectively
2. The link texts do NOT change dynamically

```
  $(document).ready(function()
      $('div.container').each(function(){
          if ($(this).find('a.taglink').eq(0).text()=="go"){
              $(this).find('div.a').removeClass('span6').addClass('span12');
              $(this).find('div.b').removeClass('span6').addClass('span12');    
          }
      }
  });
```

Comment: The id's dont matter at all infact, the classes are span1-12 since im using bootstrap, I put a/b etc in just to distinguish between which divs im talking about in my example.

Comment: the link texts are generated in the backend as this is for a blog, it would differ from post to post with some having the 'go' text and others not which would in turn differ the number of the links with innerhtml 'go' on a page (since multiple posts per page)

Comment: I suggest putting a `$(document).ready(function(){
  ... your code here ...
});` around it so it happens when his page loads.

Comment: ok but then would it not need to check for the taglink's innerhtml?

Comment: I'm confused now, the point of this post was to ask for help with how to go about making an event listener for taglinks innerhtml and then use certain values of it to change the span6 class divs to spanwhatever.

Comment: That's what this function will do. Event listeners around innerHTML are a BAD idea, as they are not widely supported by most browsers. This function will indeed do what you ask it, as for ids, they matter because a page with duplicate ids is an invalid page and will break javascript in all kinds of fun and unpredictable ways...

Comment: Also @LeeMeador thanks, edited as per your (excellent) suggestion